# What is the difference between percentile function in Numpy and Excel?

Tags: python, excel, difference, percentile

I am using Python to do some calculation on a data series. The goal of the calculation is to remove the top 5 percentile data from the series. As an acceptance criteria, the manual calculation in excel is done in parallel. I need to meet the manual calculation results to get my code passed.

However, the results from Python and Excel are different from one another.

I've excluded lots of elements and finally narrowed down to the percentile function.

In Python, I do the percentile calculation (for the 5th percentile) as following:

```
import numpy as np

return np.percentile(values, percentile)
```

and in Excel, I used:

```
=PERCENTILE.INC(E8:E143, 0.05)
```

where the `values` is the same as `E8:E143`.

Could anyone explain the difference between these functions? And if possible, please list out the equations.

Many thanks.

==========================================================

UPDATE:

The `percentile` used in the Python code is 5.0.

Comment: What did you use for the percentile in the `np.percentile` function? You should put in `5.0`, not `0.05`, to get the fifth percentile.

Comment: @CactusWoman Hi There, thanks for your comment. Yes, I used `5.0` in the Python code.

Comment: I get the same number with both numpy and excel.